# How do I solve a problem with my DB connection and require?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an Express app that was created with express generator. I have a standard `app.js` file that exports app. I also have a standard `www` file that imports `app` and is a starting point of the application:

```
const app = require('../app')
const debug = require('debug')('img-final:server')
const http = require('http')
const Mongo = require('../utils/dbConnection/dbConnection')
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
app.set('port', port)

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
const server = http.createServer(app)

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

async function startServer() {
  try {
    await Mongo.init()
    debug('Connected correctly to DB')
    server.listen(port)
  } catch (err) {
    debug(err)
  }
}

startServer()

//some more unrelated code.
```

I also have a  utility file for connecting to db `dbConnection.js`:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

class Mongo {
  async init() {
    const client = new MongoClient(`mongodb://localhost:27017/img-new`, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    await client.connect()
    this.db = client.db('img-new')
  }

  getConnection() {
    return this.db
  }
}

module.exports = new Mongo()
```

My problem is that when I start my app `const app = require('../app')` is obviously running first, and wherever in my app route controllers I use `getConnection()`, the connection is `undefined` at that point because my `Mongo.init()` is running after  `const app = require('../app')`.

I'm trying to understand how to solve it in sane way. I guess I can move all `require`'s and all other code inside `startServer` after `await Mongo.init()` , but it seems like there should be a better solution. Thank you.

Edit:
Is this an OK solution ?

```
const debug = require('debug')('img-final:server')
const http = require('http')
const Mongo = require('../utils/dbConnection/dbConnection')



async function startServer() {
  try {
    await Mongo.init()

    const app = require('../app')
    
    const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000')
    app.set('port', port)
    const server = http.createServer(app)
    server.listen(port)

  } catch (err) {
    debug(err)
  }
}

startServer()
```

Comment: I always use mongoose. It solves that problem really good and is well documented

Answer (score 0):

I have 1 solution but I'm not sure it satisfies your expectation.

In the `getConenction` method you check if `this.db` is `undefined`. If it's a case, just call init() method then return `this.db`. If not, you return `this.db` directly.
The code is like this :

```
 async getConnection() {
    if(!this.db) {
         // connection to db is not established yet, we call `init` method
         await this.init();
    }
    
    // this.db is defined here, we return the connection
    return this.db;
  }
```

And you don't have to call `await Mongo.init()` in the  `startServer()` function

Comment: I've noticed that  `getConnection()` becomes async, so the code to call this function is affected

Comment: It's an interesting approach, however the problem is that when you return something from `async ` function, you get a Promise. You need to await it later, and it causes some other problems . For example, I can't await  my DB connection in the constructor of another class.

Comment: Hi @Noob yea, you don't have a choice. You have to do an await, because in the general case, you don't know how long it takes to connect to the DB. 

If you assume that the database would be connected before the first time you make a getConnection(), this will cause all sorts of problems that are hard to detect.

If I have convinced you, then you should use @ĐăngKhoaĐinh's code, but you should also check if a connection is also underway. If you don't, you might potentially have multiple `this.init()` being called.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by Đăng Khoa Đinh is the right direction. I add a bit of defensive coding to prevent multiple `this.init()` being called at the same time. Note: I did not code against errors while connecting.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

class Mongo {

    init() {

        // Gerard we set isConnected to a promise
        this.isConnected = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

            const client = new MongoClient(`mongodb://localhost:27017/img-new`, {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
            })
            await client.connect()
            this.db = client.db('img-new')
            resolve();

        });
    }

    isConnected = null;

    async getConnection() {
        if(this.isConnected === null) {
            // connection to db is not established yet, we call `init` method
            this.init();
        }

        // Now either the DB is already connected, or a connection is in progress. We wait.
        await this.isConnected;

        // this.db is defined here, we return the connection
        return this.db;
    }
}

module.exports = new Mongo()
```

The caller will then just do

```
connection = await Mongo.getConnection();
```